# Exceute a string entered using fgets as a shell command in C

Tags: c, shell

I'm a C newbie. I want to enter a string using fgets and have it execute as a shell command. I know its possible to do something like

```
echo `ls`
```

in Perl. I want to do something similar in C. What am I doing wrong? Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
printf("Enter a command: ");
fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

if(prefix("ls", buf) || prefix("mv", buf) || prefix("pwd", buf) || prefix("mkdir", buf)){
    strip_newline(buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("echo `%s`", buf);
}
```

Comment: Did you try using system command?http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm

Comment: It's a bad idea (for security reasons) but have a look at [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`system`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm) command.

> The C library function int system(const char *command) passes the
>   command name or program name specified by command to the host
>   environment to be executed by the command processor and returns after
>   the command has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
printf("echo `%s`", buf);
```

with

```
system(buf);
```

and try again.